# How to change TextView text color inside a ListView when list item is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am trying to change text color of a TextView inside a listview item.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);

               ViewGroup selectedGroup = (ViewGroup)view;

                ((TextView)selectedGroup.getChildAt(4)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#336699"));
                String mID =String.valueOf(((TextView) selectedGroup.getChildAt(4)).getText());
            }
        });
```

But nothing happens, I can get text value of the textview, though. What might be wrong in this code?

This is, by the way, my listView layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#336699"
        android:id="@+id/questionTitle"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:id="@+id/questionDate"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/questionContent" android:value=""/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/questionSenderContact" android:value=""/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:visibility="invisible"
              android:id="@+id/messageID" android:value=""/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** I was getting wrong textview. Index of it was not 4, but 0. Sorry for a question caused by lack of attention.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
public View row;

your_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

if (row != null) {
    row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
}
row = v;
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent_green);
)};
```

Comment: the 'v' returned by click listener is a 'viewGroup'. Thus, you can't assign some attributes, which you want to do it to a textview inside it, directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new StateListDrawable like you did before but with black as default color and white when pressed.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/black" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/black" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/black" />
<item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Now for in the TextView change the text color to the new drawable:

```
android:textColor="@color/list_item_text"
```

More on StateListDrawables: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: @zgrkpnr89 could you try this one?

Comment: Make sure that the selector is in the right place.
You need to put the above selector in a folder 'color' under the resource.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to set textview as tag to the clickable button as:

```
...
view.setOnClickListener(this);
view.setTag(textView);
...


public void onclick(View v){
  ...
  TextView textView = (TextView)v.getTag();
  textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));
  ...
}
```