# How to change a TextView's (inside a listview) text color according to a variable?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to do it in adapter like the following

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        ZgrViewHolder holder;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        QuestionObject questionObject = arrayList_.get(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.zgr_listview_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ZgrViewHolder();
            holder.questionTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionTitle);
            holder.questionDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionDate);
            holder.questionContent = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionContent);
            holder.senderContact = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionSenderContact);
            holder.messageID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageID);

            holder.questionTitle.setText(questionObject.mailTitle);
            holder.messageID.setText(String.valueOf(questionObject.messageID));
            holder.questionDate.setText(questionObject.Date_);
            holder.questionContent.setText(questionObject.mailContent);
            holder.senderContact.setText(questionObject.senderContact);

            if (questionObject.ReadState == 1){
                holder.questionTitle.setTextColor(Color.argb(100,100,100,100));
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ZgrViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

But when listview is complete, none of the textviews has the color I assign. I debug and `ReadState` variable is sometimes 1, but still nothing.

Comment: *Always* update *every* widget on *every* `getView()` call. Right now, you are only updating them when you inflate the layout, not when you recycle rows.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just realized, Sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ZgrViewHolder holder;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    QuestionObject questionObject = arrayList_.get(position);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.zgr_listview_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ZgrViewHolder();
        holder.questionTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionTitle);
        holder.questionDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionDate);
        holder.questionContent = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionContent);
        holder.senderContact = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionSenderContact);
        holder.messageID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageID);


        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ZgrViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        holder.questionTitle.setText(questionObject.mailTitle);
        holder.messageID.setText(String.valueOf(questionObject.messageID));
        holder.questionDate.setText(questionObject.Date_);
        holder.questionContent.setText(questionObject.mailContent);
        holder.senderContact.setText(questionObject.senderContact);

        if (questionObject.ReadState == 1){

        holder.questionTitle.setTextColor(Color.argb(100,100,100,100));
        return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now everything is clear. Listview calls getView everytime it is scrolled.Got it.

Comment: @zgrkpnr89 i answered another one of your questions today
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764758/how-to-change-textview-text-color-inside-a-listview-when-list-item-is-clicked/31764992#31764992
let me know if it works

Comment: Now there is another problem. It worked perfect, but when I scrolled all of them gets this color. Before scrolling nothing happens, now after scroll all of them (no matter it's ReadState) gets the color.

Comment: thats because you have to set the other color in else case because convertview uses the last state and color is never changed again

Comment: I did it now, but it's still the same. all of 'em gets the color. Any other idea?

Comment: you did this right? 

 if (questionObject.ReadState == 1){
        holder.questionTitle.setTextColor(Color.argb(100,100,100,100));
} else {
     holder.questionTitle.setTextColor(Color.argb(...othercolor...));}

Comment: No, I did it wrong. Now I altered the code as you said. it works perfectly. Thank you for your attention, really

Comment: check the other answer too..it will help if you are still struck on that

Comment: I made an edit there=) problem was my lack of attention=)

Answer (score 0):

Please assign textview color out side this piece of code   if(convertView == null) {} 
Thanks and feedback me